# PHP strftime returns different values different systems with same locale installed

Tags: php, locale, strftime

I ran into a behavior which I can not explain. The function `strftime` returns different values on different systems.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,'fr_FR');
$time = strtotime('2015-04-08'); // just to start with, setlocale independent
echo strftime('%x',$time);
```

will output on Mac OSX/PHP5.6

```
"08.04.2015"
```

and on Linux Cent OS/PHP5.6

```
"08/04/2015"
```

Looking up date formats for France on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_France) the second one should be official right. But everything I've seen so far from France, they use more likely the first one.

I checked if the French locale is installed on shell and in PHP.

```
$ locale -a
intlcal_get_available_locales();
```

Can I check what PHP uses as format to generate the output? Can I set the format for '%x' manually for a language.

Comment: (Just since your are wondering, the second format is used waaaaay more  than the first one in France.)

Comment: Did you check the _return value_ of `setlocale` …?

Comment: thanks for the info @ClémentMalet . `setlocale(LC_TIME, 0)` returns `fr_FR` as string. When the second format is used most, than I guess there is something than with my PHP on Mac OSX.

Comment: On MacOS is in file `/usr/share/locale/fr_FR/LC_TIME` on line 58 `%d.%m.%Y`. Which doesn't fit to the definition a date should be `d/m/Y`.

I can not find a french LC_TIME file on CentOS somehow.